# How to Preventing Host Header Attack in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: apache, security, ubuntu-14.04, host, audit

If we send a request from any host like example.com our server gives back a HTTP 1.1 200 OK response status.

In correct condition it should show either 302, 400 or 404 error message (not found response) status. At current condition it is showing 200 OK response message, when its send through our host like xx.xxx.xx.xx.

For example, if we sent this request:

> GET /web/ HTTP/1.1 **Host: example.com** User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
>   NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0 Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Connection: close
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

We get this response:

> **HTTP/1.1 200 OK** Date: Thu, 02 Mar 2017 15:23:20 GMT Server:
>   figi_Server X-Frame-Options: deny Strict-Transport-Security: 1 Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options:
>   sameorigin X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Using

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.
Web server: Apache 2.2.
Virtual machine running both.
```

Please go through Screen Shot Of Issue for better Understanding of Issue:

[image]

Comment: You have a VirtualHost set up to accept connections for any host (*:80), just don't have that and you will achieve what you want, or deny access to this VirtualHost.